# How to get independent from GLEW dll file

Tags: opengl, mingw

I'm literally an absolute noob in GL. I just wrote my first GLEW piece of code yesterday:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glfw.h>

int main(void)
{
    glfwInit();
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_FSAA_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwOpenWindow(640, 480, 8, 8, 8, 0, 24, 0, GLFW_WINDOW);

    glewInit();

    glfwSetWindowTitle("OpenGL Rules!");
    glfwEnable( GLFW_STICKY_KEYS );

    do{
    glfwSwapBuffers();
    }while( glfwGetKey( GLFW_KEY_ESC ) != GLFW_PRESS && glfwGetWindowParam( GLFW_OPENED ) );    
}
```

This compiles just fine with (using mingw on win8 x64):

```
gcc opengl.c -lglfw -lglew32 -lopengl32
```

However, in order to run the output, I have to copy the glew32.dll to the same directory from which I'm running the program. Is there a way to get independent from the dll? Like, compiling once and using without having to carry the dll around?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `#define GLEW_STATIC` before you #include the GLEW headers, then link to `glew32s` instead of `glew32` and you'll statically link to GLEW.

According to http://glew.sourceforge.net/install.html you can also directly use the glew.c and glew.h files in your own project, but I haven't tried that; the GLEW_STATIC method works well enough.